# how to remove item in listview using button inside the arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Im trying to remove an item displayed in my `ListView` using a button inside my `ArrayAdapter`. I saw `getPosition` method in the `ArrayAdapter` that returns the index number of the item, but I dont know to use it in the remove method of the `ArrayAdapter`. How can I do this? need help please.

arrayAdapter

```
public class myOrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myOrder> {


ArrayList<myOrder> list;

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView tableNum;
        TextView itemName;
        TextView itemQuantity;
        TextView custName;
        Button btnStatus;
    }

    public myOrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<myOrder> orderList) {
        super(context, 0,orderList);
        this.list = orderList;
    }

    @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final myOrder orderList = getItem(position);

            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            if(convertView == null){


                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);

                viewHolder.tableNum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableNum);
                viewHolder.itemName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
                viewHolder.custName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.custName);
                viewHolder.itemQuantity = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
                viewHolder.btnStatus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusButton);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }

            else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }


            viewHolder.tableNum.setText("Order for Table: "+orderList.getTable_id());
            viewHolder.itemName.setText(orderList.getItem_name());
            viewHolder.custName.setText("Customer Name: " + orderList.getCust_name());
            viewHolder.itemQuantity.setText("QTY: " + orderList.getQuantity());


            if(orderList.getStatus_id() == 1){
                viewHolder.btnStatus.setText("Ready");
                viewHolder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"" + getPosition(orderList),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // Remove item codes here..
                                list.remove(position);

                    }
                });
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: remove the item from orderList and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: 20 seconds late. What @Raghunandan said

Comment: can you please provide some sample codes? I tried using the remove method of the arrayadapter with the codes remove(getPosition(orderList)) but it turns to red and says create a method remove with parameter of int.

Comment: use `ArrayAdapter#remove(T object)` it is not `ArrayAdapter#remove(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter also has a method remove(T Object) which can remove the item from the list or you can remove it from the ArrayList. 
First of all get order in getView

```
final myOrder order = getItem(position);
```

orderList is the ArrayList that you passed in Constructor.

```
viewHolder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Your Toast message

        orderList.remove(position);
    }
});

notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i tried what you say, it worked, but when i try to remove the item from the top most, it doesn't remove it, but removes a random item below.

Comment: @newBieUser0829 You are setting the button text and click listener only when status id is 1. If it's not 1 you don't do set anything on the button, this may lead to some issues related to view recycling. Can you first just remove that condition and try the remove part.

Comment: what I did is that I create a new public Integer variable outside the getview, and cast the value of the position to it, I tried tossing it a couple of times, and saw that the value of position is inconsistent while the value of the new Integer is consistent, so I tried using the new Integer and somehow got the result that I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewHolder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"" + getPosition(orderList),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         list.remove(position); //List/ArrayList of order in your program.

            } 
        }); 
        notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: instead of "getContext()", You should get context from "view" and use in toast. So You will avoid leaks.

Comment: orderList already has the value of getItem(position), when I user the orderList again the next line of codes are the getter/setter from myOrder class.

Comment: What's the arraylist you are using in your adapter class? You need to remove the item from that